# Questions about stationary and limiting distributions of a discrete-time Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes

For a discrete-time Markov chain,

1. Is it right that there are no more
   than one limiting distribution,
   i.e., limiting distribution is
   unique if any?
2. If the chain has more than one
   recurrence irreducible classes, then
   is it right that the limiting
   distribution does not exist?
3. If the chain has only one recurrence
   class, does existence of transient
   states not affect the existence of a
   limiting distribution?
4. When both limiting and stationary
   distributions exist, is it possible
   there is some stationary
   distribution that is not a limiting
   distribution?
5. If interpreting the limiting
   distribution as limit of the
   distribution of $X_n$, in what sense
   does the sequence of distribution
   measures converge?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: -1: These look like exam questions, and I think you should take the effort to try to look up the answers in your textbook first.  If you have specific questions about what you read, feel free to ask them here.

Comment: Maybe this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24759/equilibrium-distributions-of-markov-chains will be helpful.

Comment: @Byron: Thanks for the link! It is helpful indeed! I now have some new questions updated to replace the old ones. Would appreciate if you could read and/or reply.

Comment: @Nate: Thanks! I have read several posts in this site and some theorems in some books, which basically answered my old questions. Now I have some new questions and just replaced my old ones with them. Would appreciate if you could read and/or reply.