# Different limiting distributions but they both satisfy same equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, markov-chains, markov-process

I needed to find the limiting distribution of the matrix

> $$\pmatrix{ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0}$$

Instead of $\pi$ I'll use $A, B$ and $C$ because that might be easier to read.

To solve this, I got

$$A = B + \frac{1}{2}C$$
$$B = \frac{1}{2}C$$
$$C = A$$

Now to solve this, I ended up getting $A = C$ and I got $A = 2B$. I also need to satisfy $A + B + C = 1$. So, I said let $A = \frac{1}{4}, B = \frac{1}{2}, C = \frac{1}{4}$, which satisfies all my equations. But in the answers they say that $A = \frac{1}{5}, B = \frac{2}{5}, C = \frac{1}{5}$, which also satisfy the equations.

How did I get mine wrong? Obviously it matters what the limiting distribution is, so how am I supposed to tell which is the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers are wrong...

The system of three equations can be readily rewritten as $A=2B=C$ hence the only solution such that $A+B+C=1$ is $(A,B,C)=(\frac25,\frac15,\frac25)$.

If $(A,B,C)=(\frac14,\frac12,\frac14)$ (your solution), then $A\ne2B\ne C$.

If $(A,B,C)=(\frac15,\frac25,\frac15)$ (*their* solution), then $A+B+C\ne1$.

Comment: Huh? How did you get this? If $A = 2b$ and $A = \frac{2}{5}, B = \frac{1}{5}$ then isn't $A = \frac{B}{2}$?

Comment: Well... no. $ $

Comment: Ok, I managed to get $A = C$ and $A = 2B$, but how do I then decide the values for $A, B$ and $C$?

Comment: Also, how doesn't it? If I put in $\frac{2}{5}$ in my calculator, then divide by $2$, this gives me $\frac{1}{5} = B$.

EDIT: Ohhh, so $\frac{A}{2} = B$ then?

Comment: Please concentrate: if $A=C$ and $A=2B$, then $A+B+C=(2B)+B+(2B)=5B$ hence, since $A+B+C=1$, one gets $B=$ $____$.

Comment: $5B = 1 \implies B = \frac{1}{5}$. Then do $2A = 1 - \frac{1}{5} \implies A = \frac{2}{5} = C$.

Answer (score 1):

Their answers are the essentially same as yours, just not normalized--they don't satisfy $A+B+C = 1$. As such, I would consider your answer "more correct" than theirs.

(Though, as Did points out, they're both wrong...)

Comment: It says this is for a "limiting distribution" not stationary, mistake in my post, does this change things?

Comment: No, it shouldn't make a difference in this case. Limiting and stationary distributions are not always the same, but here they will be, and it still needs to satisfy $A+B+C=1$.

Comment: This bit about them "not always being the same thing" has confused me because they want me to work out both in the next question, but I can't find out the difference. Can you tell me or give me a good link or something that will help me find out please?

Comment: @Kaish [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24759/equilibrium-distributions-of-markov-chains) old question may be helpful.

Comment: That just tells me about equilibrium distribution, so that could still be eithe limiting or stationary right? It doesn't clarify any difference between them.

Comment: @Kaish whoops, that wasn't the question I meant to link. Try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/equilibrium-distribution-steady-state-distribution-stationary-distribution-and) one.